# Is naam japa better than mantra japa in kaliyuga?

Tags: practice

It is said by some that in kaliyuga, naam japa is the **only** means of salvation.

Even if we ignore this extreme position, does it imply that naam japa is definitely better than mantra japa in kaliyuga ?

Comment: Good question.Well there is no such thing as better. It is all relative. If you are suffering from sore throat, tomato soup is better than fruit juice. If you are suffering from heat, then fruit juice is better. Similarly, depending on the sadhaka, a different practice is recommended. Some saints say that nama japa is the best. Some saints say that self-enquiry is the best. Some saints say that yoga is the best. Only thing I can say is generally 'any japa is better than nothing'. So once we make a start, if we are sincere, God will guide us on to whatever is suitable for us. All the best.

Comment: "naam japa" is itself a type of "mantra japa"...

Comment: @Sai Sometimes personal opinions give WRONG infos.In this case ,ur statement "Well there is no such thing as better" is a wrong one.Unless of course u consider urself a better authority than Shastras themselves.

Comment: @Rickross Good question. Please read the full comment. It would clarify what I was trying to say. :)

Comment: @Sai.Nothing personal.But IMO u should not comment like "Well there is nothing like better" on Scriptural matters unless u can prove ur point by citing Scriptures.Such authoritative comments suit only Gods and those Saints/Rishis whose Sahasrara Chakra has been pierced.U shud add "I think"",Afaik" "IMO" etc to make ur comments humble.

Comment: @Rickross Your opinion is fair. I would encourage you to put it on Meta Stack Exchange if you're really serious about imposing such a rule. However you have to be careful not to be too extreme. To a certain extent all answers are merely opinions. For example, which scriptures are considered Shastras according to you? According to Vaishnavas this number is different. According to Iyers, this number is different. According to Shaivites this number is different. Based on what do you conclude that an answer is in accordance with Shastras? And will that not be your own opinion! Good luck

Comment: @Rickross Secondly how do you tell whether a saint/rishi has awakened his or her sahsasrara chakra! If I quote Ramana Maharishi, would you accept it as valid? How about Yogananda? Is it your opinion that these saints have awakened their Sahasrara? Or is it your opinion that these saints have not awakened it? A general rule of thumb is good. But it's important not to read too much into the technicalities and read the overall meaning. Good luck

Comment: @Sai, *"It is all relative."* Perfectly said! Relativity is not limited to scientific equation, but to everything else. Even 2 siblings suffering from same disease, will require different medicines. Being a liberal, I would bring this a notch further. (Inspired from Gita), everyone is actually on the path towards the ultimate one. Be it a saint or a terrorist. Theist or atheist. Just their speed, direction & methods are different. Certain unfortunate ppl are too extreme about the books they read & regard it as only *Dharma*. Don't be worried by them, even they are also on path to the One only!

Comment: @Sai1)I don't think opinion based answers are accepted here.2)Number of Shastras are also more or less well known & fixed and one can cite any of them to validate his points.3)You can get away with authoratative opinions like that in comments because theres no rule as such preventing you. but i feel its always better to add I think to be ..more humble.

Comment: @Rickross Yes your points are once again fair. I will leave it to you to re-read my comments and determine the best course of action. I do agree that it's better in general to preface with IMO, etc. But wanted to point out certain considerations in my previous comments. Of late I have reduced writing answers because of time constraints, therefore I leave comments because of the fact that it is a little more liberal when it comes to citing references. I do have some good references, I will try to put in an answer with those :). I do appreciate your opinion on this matter :). Thanks

Comment: @iammilind Yes you're absolutely right! Everyone is on their own path to liberation. Some achieve it sooner, some later. Although a terrorist, Valmiki, obtained the grace of God and changed his ways to become a saint. However one must be careful for the law of Karma ensures that every action has an equal reverse action. Therefore before you do anything think if you're ok with the fact that whatever you did will return back to you. :)

Comment: @Sai, off late I think that we need not worry about law of Karma, as anyway it works perfectly fine. Why to keep testing or thinking about it? To me, "giving up the **doer-ship**" seems better. BTW, VAlmiky is a good example, though he turned to saint. There were terrorists who never improved, like Kamsa, Madhu, ShishupAla. Yet got quicker liberation. See [this](https://goo.gl/a0wSZr) page in Krishna's words, how ShishupAla terrorized other kingdoms. Later he is slain by Krishna & in front of everyone he gets (possible) Moksha by merging to Krishna. I may delete this later to unload this post.

Comment: @iammilind Yes what you have realized is true. In Bhakti yoga they call it 'self-surrender'. i.e. let karma do its thing. I am no more me. It is God that acts through me, thinks through me, etc. In Jnana yoga they call it 'silence'. i.e. there is nothing left to realize. I am That. I am not this body nor mind. Therefore there is no more necessity for me to act, nor is there a necessity to inact. :) The former comment is of a different nature (in day to day life). If the law of karma dictates that all that I do will come back to me it is simple inference that by doing 'good' , I get back good

Answer (score 8):

First of all one need to understand that Nama Japa is different from Mantra Japa.A Mantra is one which is always preceded by the Pranava Beeja OM.Otherwise the mantra is lifeless.(See [this](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/14769/what-is-the-origin-of-the-sloka-mantraanaam-pallavo-vaaso) or [this](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/10550/is-reciting-vedic-mantras-without-being-preceded-by-om-condemned-somewhere-in) question)Nothing of that sort applies to Nama Japa.

Also,a Mantra is always associated with a corresponding *"Viniyoga Mantra"* which is uttered to "unlock" the full potential of the actual Mantra by acknowledging the Risi,Devata and Chanda of the Mantra.

Moreover,performing Kara ,Anga-adi Nyasas are often mandatory for attaining success in Mantra Japa.*No such restrictions apply to Nama Japa.*

In Puja & Yajna we use Mantra (Japa) & not Nama Japa.So,Mantra Japa is essentially (another form of)Worship or Yajna and is distinct from Nama Japa or Nama Samkeertana in the stricter sense.

Now,from the [Dharma Bindu](http://www.kamakoti.org/kamakoti/articles/Dharma%20Bindu.pdf)(the essence of all Dharma Shastras):

> Vishnu Purana: Sarve Brahma vadavyanti sampraptetun Kaloau yuge, Naanu
>   tishthanti Maitreya shishnodara parayanaah/ Yada yadaasataam haanih
>   Vedamargaanu saarinaam, Tadaa tadaa Kaler - vriddhih anumeyaa
>   vichakshanaih// Veda Vyaasauvaacha: Yatkrute dashabhirvarshaih
>   tretaayaam vaayanenatu Dvaapare tacchamaasena hyahoraatrena tatlalou/
>   Dhyaayan Krite yajan yagjnaih Tretaayaam Dwapare archayan, Yadaapnoti
>   tadaapnoti Kalou samkeerta Keshavam/ Naaradiye/ Hare Keshava Govinda
>   Vaasudeva Janaarddana, Iteetayanti nityam sahitaan badhate Kalih//
>   Shiva Shankara Rudreti Nilakantha Trilochana, Iteerayanti ye nityam
>   sahitaan baadhate Kalih/ Shiva Shankara Rudreti Neelakantha
>   Trilochana, Iteerayanti ye nityam sahitaan baadhate Kalih/ (Vishnu
>   Purana details Yuga dharmas as follows: In Kali Yuga, every one
>   discusses about Brahma Jnaana but none is really interested in it
>   since they are overwhelmed of selfishness, centric pysche and sex but
>   none really is serious in favour of Brahma Jnaana; as and when there
>   occurs a danger to the Virtuous, there is the upgradation of evil
>   forces and infringement of virtue, and the signs of Kali Yuga become
>   prominent and clear. Vyasa states: What ever deeds of virtue are
>   performed in ten years in Krita yuga are as dispensed with or equal to
>   those peformed in one Ayana on Treta Yuga, one month in one Dvapara
>   yuga and even in single day-night on Kali Yuga. **1)The rewards of
>   virtue by of Tapas during KritaYuga are as good as Yagjnas in Treta
>   yuga, worships in DvaparaYuga and even ‘Samkeertanas’ rendering Sacred
>   Songs in Kali yuga)**
>
> Narada Brahmarshi that states the soulful singing of Narayana as: Here
>   Keshava Govinda Vaasudeva Janardana Iteerayanti nityam sahitaan
>   baadhate Kalih/ Or alternatively as Shiva Shankara Rudreti Neelakantha
>   Tricochana, Itirtayanti ye nityam sahitaan baadhate Kalih/ **2)That is
>   either render Hari Smarana or Hara smarana as above! Kali Yuga would
>   never ever torment sincere prayers with the naamas as mentioned above.
>   Such indeed are the Yuga Dharmas!**

From highlighted portion **1** we can conclude that what is worship( or Mantra Japa) in Dwapara , Yajna(or Mantra japa) in Treta  is Nama Samkeertana(or Nama Japa) in Kali .This   implicitly implies **that Nama Japa is more effective than Mantra Japa in Kali yuga.**

Highlighted portion **2** also declares the same thing viz-*Nama Japa is the best protection from all kinds of evil in Kali Yuga.*.This also implies that Nama Japa has more effectiveness than Mantra Japa in Kali Yuga.

But the statement that "Nama Japa is the only mode of salvation **for everyone** in Kali" seems to be an exaggerated one &  is possibly not true.

The "Chaitanya Charitra Amrita" however says :

> "Naam Bina Kali kaale naai aar dharmo,Sarva Mantra Saar Naam-Ei Sastro
>   Mormo"(Bengali)

Meaning-There is no Dharma in Kali other than Nama ,Nama is the essence of all Mantras & this is the essence of all Shastras.

Comment: Can we sing Naam Jaap...I have seen many who sing Naam...like (Ram Ram Ram Ram) but in musical tone. IMO it's more like keertana than Nama Japa.

Comment: Yes its Nama Sankirtana .. it can be done too @LSSJBroly