# Are there any positives of kaliyug?

Tags: shiva, krishna, kali-yuga

What are some positives of kaliyug?
And how to safeguard oneself in kaliyug?

Answer (score 12):

Some Puranas state that in Kali Yuga getting Moksha is easier compared to the previous ages.

For example, the [Bhagavata Purana](https://vedabase.io/en/library/sb/12/3/) states:

> Text 51: My dear King, although Kali-yuga is an ocean of faults,
> **there is still one good quality about this age**: Simply by chanting the Hare Kṛṣṇa mahā-mantra, one can become free from material bondage
> and be promoted to the transcendental kingdom.

In the previous Yugas, for getting Moksha  it used to require a lot of effort and tapasya but in Kali Yuga for achieving the same simply Nama Sankirtana (chanting holy names of God) is enough. So, this is a plus point of Kali.

Same thing is mentioned in other Puranas as quoted in the book ["Dharma Bindu"](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/15349/4732):

> Vishnu Purana: Sarve Brahma vadavyanti sampraptetun Kaloau yuge, Naanu
> tishthanti Maitreya shishnodara parayanaah/ Yada yadaasataam haanih
> Vedamargaanu saarinaam, Tadaa tadaa Kaler - vriddhih anumeyaa
> vichakshanaih// Veda Vyaasauvaacha: Yatkrute dashabhirvarshaih
> tretaayaam vaayanenatu Dvaapare tacchamaasena hyahoraatrena tatlalou/
> Dhyaayan Krite yajan yagjnaih Tretaayaam Dwapare archayan, Yadaapnoti
> tadaapnoti Kalou samkeerta Keshavam/ Naaradiye/ Hare Keshava Govinda
> Vaasudeva Janaarddana, Iteetayanti nityam sahitaan badhate Kalih//
> Shiva Shankara Rudreti Nilakantha Trilochana, Iteerayanti ye nityam
> sahitaan baadhate Kalih/ Shiva Shankara Rudreti Neelakantha
> Trilochana, Iteerayanti ye nityam sahitaan baadhate Kalih/ (Vishnu
> Purana details Yuga dharmas as follows: In Kali Yuga, every one
> discusses about Brahma Jnaana but none is really interested in it
> since they are overwhelmed of selfishness, centric pysche and sex but
> none really is serious in favour of Brahma Jnaana; as and when there
> occurs a danger to the Virtuous, there is the upgradation of evil
> forces and infringement of virtue, and the signs of Kali Yuga become
> prominent and clear. Vyasa states: What ever deeds of virtue are
> performed in ten years in Krita yuga are as dispensed with or equal to
> those peformed in one Ayana on Treta Yuga, one month in one Dvapara
> yuga and even in single day-night on Kali Yuga. **1)The rewards of
> virtue by of Tapas during KritaYuga are as good as Yagjnas in Treta
> yuga, worships in DvaparaYuga and even ‘Samkeertanas’ rendering Sacred
> Songs in Kali yuga)**
>
> Narada Brahmarshi that states the soulful singing of Narayana as: Here
> Keshava Govinda Vaasudeva Janardana Iteerayanti nityam sahitaan
> baadhate Kalih/ Or alternatively as Shiva Shankara Rudreti Neelakantha
> Tricochana, Itirtayanti ye nityam sahitaan baadhate Kalih/ **2)That is
> either render Hari Smarana or Hara smarana as above! Kali Yuga would
> never ever torment sincere prayers with the naamas as mentioned above.
> Such indeed are the Yuga Dharmas!**

Comment: Beautiful answer.

Comment: Thanks Harihara ... @Harihara

Answer (score 7):

Kali Yuga yields the fruits of good acts immediately and only sinful deeds and not sinful thoughts matter.

> Parikshit, who was like a honey-bee in grasping the essential good in
> everything, abstained from killing Kali, **because there is one great
> excellence pertaining to his age – whatever good you do fructifies
> immediately, but not so the evil deeds; and besides, in Kali’s age sin
> accrues only to sinful deeds and not to sinful thoughts.** Kali is like
> one who is cowardly before the brave, but brave before the cowardly.
> He holds no fear for the good, but like a wolf he is always vigilant
> and alert to pounce upon those who are thoughtless and unobservant.

**Srimad Bhagavata Purana translated by Swami Tapasyananda I.18.7**