# What is the origin of the Sloka "Mantraanaam Pallavo Vaaso..."?

Tags: scripture, mantras, shloka, om

The sloka is to be found [here](https://www.hindujagruti.org/hinduism/knowledge/article/what-is-a-bijamantra.html).

> मंत्राणां पल्‍लवो वासो । मंत्राणां प्रणव: शिर: । शिर: पल्‍लव संयुक्तो
>   । कामधुक्‌ भवेत्‌ ।।
>
> The meaning: The letters or words in a mantra constitute its body and
>   the Om at its beginning, is the head. If both the head and the body
>   are present then with that mantra one’s aspirations are fulfilled.

By origin i mean scriptural origin.

Also, as one can see this info is related to my [this](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/10550/is-reciting-vedic-mantras-without-being-preceded-by-om-condemned-somewhere-in) question .Because this sloka clearly states that a mantra if recited without OM at its start bears no fruit.

Comment: I found the verse in a Shaivite work called the Diksha Prakasha: http://tinyurl.com/dikshaprakasha "atha viśeṣamāha - mantrāṇāṃ pallavo vāso mantrāṇāṃ pallavaḥ śiraḥ । śiraḥpallavasaṃyukto mantraḥ puṣṭādisādhakaḥ ॥ huṃkārapallavopeto māraṇe brāhmaṇaṃ vinā । yantrabhañjanakāryeṣu sughorabhayanāśane ॥ vaṣaḍantaḥ prakalpayastu grahavādhāvināśakaḥ । uccāṭane tu samprokto mantraḥ phaṭpallavānvitaḥ ॥ ete pallavāstu tattatkarmaṇi caṇḍīpāṭhepi ślokādau yojyāḥ । tathā" It seems to be quoting something called Visheshama, but I'm not sure what that is.

Comment: And I found a close variant of the verse in a work called the Srividyarnava Tantra: http://tinyurl.com/srividyarnavatantra "iti | trailokyaḍāmaratantre - mantrāṇāṃ pallavo nyāso mantrāṇāṃ praṇavaḥ śiraḥ | śiraḥpallavasaṃyukto mantraḥ kāmadughāphalaḥ || nyāsaṃ vinā bhavenmūkaḥ suptaḥ syādāsanaṃ vinā | pallavena vina mantro nagnaḥ sa parikīrtitaḥ ||  śirohīno mṛtaḥ prokto vṛthā mantro guruṃ vinā | hato duṣṭāya datto yo nirvīryaścādhikākṣaraḥ ||" It seems to be quoting a Shaiva or Shakta Agama called the Trailokyadamara Tantra.

Comment: Thanks.I was of the opinion that Kularnava Tantra is the source of this sloka.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan post an answer.