# Who is God? or What is God? or What is ॐ?

Tags: shiva, vishnu, brahma, om

Watched an episode (broadcast on 25/09/2014 on Life Ok) of "Devo Ke Dev Mahadev", an epic serial on Lord Shiva. From this episode i came to know that ॐ (Om/Aum) is the everything in which all universe resides, including Tridev( Brahma, Vishnu and Mahesh).

So the question arise in my mind are:

1. What is ॐ? (This is not a word so should not be a defined then)
2. Is it true that everything is in ॐ and Tridev are only a energy part of ॐ?

Hope i have explained well.

Thanks

Comment: yes, it's true that everything is in Om. Please see [this answer](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/749/38), it explains the questions you have asked.

Comment: As you said that it clears you everything about Aum/Om so I'll close your question as a duplicate, if you want to ask who is god, what is god, so consider posting separate questions with decent details your first tried to read about.