# What is Meaning of Omkar

Tags: sanskrit

What is meaning of Sanskrit word Omkar/Aumkar and Omkareshwar. Please don't tell me that its jyotirlinga, I already know it, I want to know the meaning of word Omkar.

Comment: Omkara is nothing but OM ॐ the Pranava. As Sadasiva represents ॐ , He manifested as Omakareswara Lingam near Vindhya mountains.

Comment: See [What is the significance of ॐ (Om/Aum)?](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/737/3500)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mandukya Upanishad is the shortest Upanishad with just 12 slokas.. It deals with the description of Om. Here is what it says:

> 1. **All this is the letter Om. A vivid explanation of this (is begun). All
>      that is past, present, and future is but Om. Whatever transcends the
>      three periods of time, too, is Om.**
> 2. **All this is certainly Brahman. This Self is Brahman. This Self, as such,
>      is possessed of four quarters.**
> 3. (The Self) seated in the waking state and called Vaisvanara who,
>      possessed of the consciousness of the exterior, and seven limbs and
>      nineteen mouths, enjoys the gross objects, is the first quarter.
> 4. (The Self) seated in the state of dream and called Taijasa who,
>      possessed of the consciousness of the interior, and seven limbs and
>      nineteen mouths, enjoys the subtle objects, is the second quarter.
> 5. Where the sleeper desires not a thing of enjoyment and sees not
>      any dream, that state is deep sleep. (The Self) seated in the state of
>      deep sleep and called Prajna, in whom everything is unified, who is
>      dense with consciousness, who is full of bliss, who is certainly the
>      enjoyer of bliss, and who is the door to the knowledge (of the
>      preceding two states), is the third quarter.
> 6. This is the Lord of all; this is omniscient; this is the in-dwelling
>      controller (of all); this is the source and indeed the origin and
>      dissolution of all beings.
> 7. The Fourth is thought of as that which is not conscious of the
>      internal world, nor conscious of the external world, nor conscious of
>      both the worlds, nor dense with consciousness, nor simple
>      consciousness, nor unconsciousness, which is unseen, actionless,
>      incomprehensible, uninferable, unthinkable, indescribable, whose proof
>      consists in the identity of the Self (in all states), in which all
>      phenomena come to a cessation, and which is unchanging, auspicious,
>      and non-dual. That is the Self; that is to be known.
> 8. **That same Self, from the point of view of the syllable, is Om, and
>      viewed from the stand point of the letters, the quarters are the letters,
>      and the letters are the quarters. The letters are a, u and m.**
> 9. Vaisvanara seated in the **waking state is the first letter a**, owing to
>      its all-pervasiveness or being the first. He who knows thus verily
>      accomplishes all longings and becomes the first.
> 10. Taijasa **seated in the dream is u,** the second letter (of Om), owing
>       to the similarity of excellence or intermediate position. He who knows
>       thus verily advances the bounds of his knowledge and becomes equal
>       (to all) and none who is not a knower of Brahman is born in his family.
> 11. Prajna seated in the **state of deep sleep is m**, the third letter (of
>       Om), because of his being the measure or the entity wherein all
>       become absorbed. He who knows thus measures all this and absorbs
>       all.
> 12. **That which is without letters (parts) is the Fourth, beyond
>       apprehension through ordinary means, the cessation of the
>       phenomenal world, the auspicious and the non-dual. Thus Om is
>       certainly the Self. He who knows thus enters the Self by the Self.**