# Pronunciation of Om

Tags: om, language

What is the correct pronunciation of Om? Is it Om, Aum, Oom or any other pronunciation? People pronunce it many different ways. Arya Samajials pronounce it as Oom. Chinese, Japanese and Tibetans have their own pronunciation. So, what is the correct true pronunciation of Om?

Comment: this is a duplicate of numerous questions. Do a search on AUM Om pronunciation on this site...vote to close

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the significance of ॐ (Om/Aum)?](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/737/what-is-the-significance-of-%e0%a5%90-om-aum)

Comment: I think its best to learn the pronunciation from a teacher, second best is to listen to audio, there are many online: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OdblTBfO3D8

Comment: Om is mixture of Aa+Uu+ma and pronounced as said above.
Source: my own knowledge I gained from teachers,parents

Comment: The pronunciation can vary based of different region, especially China, Tibet and Japan

Answer (score 1):

It is like saying the alphabet 'O' and Mmmmmm. So it's Ommmmm. And the humming sound which its product is the basic calming monotone that helps one to meditate. 
Focus on the hum as if you're hearing from your throat or the middle of forehead (3rd eye).
That is what has been for ages for every meditation group/religion

Answer (score 1):

Either there r 2 or there r 3 pronunciations told of Pranav. 1)ओSम् this is pluta o & ends with half m which is anunasik naad end. This pronunciation contains a+u+a+m= a+u=o & o+a = pluta o. This is told in taittiriya pratishakhya text.
2)औँ - anusvar or chandrabindu when nothing ahead r half m automatically in Sanskrit mantras. In Shukla yajurved anusvar is gkaar yukta eg. Gananam tvam ganapati gum havaamahe. & in tantra we find pronunciation ङ् of anusvar & also anusvar is told to occur only before consonants र श ष स ह ज्ञ & y l w has chandrabindu before it. Ideally. In Sanskrit. Chandrabindu allophone of n & anusvar of m but when appear last both are m automatically & no difference then. Almost all script's Om symbol or the one widely used is siddham script aum means almost all scripts use au+chandrabindu character as symbol. & as per Krishna yajurved Pathshala in Satara Maharashtra's head teacher have told me he has heard aum pronunciation of Pranav in few yajnas he attended. This is a+a+u+m.
3)ओम् = akaar to Brahma ukaar to Vishnu makaar mahesh zaaniyela onkar pradhaan Roop ganeshache as written by saint tukaram. So if we look it as akaar is Brahma tatva ukaar Vishnu tatva & mkaar mahesh tatva then previous both have 2 a 1 u 1 m. So if we look this as 3 tatvas told of onkar then 2 pronunciations exist. If we take Om as pronunciation too then 3.

Comment: You should cite some sources.