# Map Om to Create, Maintain, Destroy

Tags: creation, om

I have googled this but in vain.

Trying to find a visual that explains how Om or AUM represents creation, maintenance, and destruction.

Would like to draw parallel between OM and systems engineering cycle (create, maintain and decommission, or destroy)

I only found below so far. Please advise.

[image]

Comment: some info here - http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/737/what-is-the-significance-of-ॐ-om-aum/741#741

Comment: Do you want similar graphic or textual explanation?

Comment: @SwiftPushkar A textual explanation is helpful