# How important is difference between Om and AA-U-EM sound?

Tags: om, vedic-chanting

Some guru ask to chant **Om** sound.
Some guru ask to chant **aa-u-em** (broken Om sound into three part).

How important is this difference?
What should we chant **Om** or **aa-u-em**?

Comment: It is Om. Standard Sanskrit rules dictate that A + U combines to yield a single phonetic sound. But, some organizations do have it the other way also.

Comment: Read through the answers to this question: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/737/what-is-the-significance-of-%e0%a5%90-om-aum

Comment: Om is a single syllable

Comment: The spelling in English as OM was first popularized by a German in the 19th century. The closest way to pronounce the sanskrit sound are the English letters A-U-M. Both refer to the same sanskrit. Both should be pronounced as AUM.

Comment: @SwamiVishwananda: so many indian guru break Om sound into 3 part. Example is Sadguru from Isha fundation

Comment: Om and aa-u-em are the same thing. The guru breaks it down so it is easier to learn.